# No such plan: status24hr; a similar object exists in live mode, but a test mode key was used to make this request

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

when I am trying to use the stripe test key. 
Laravel 5.7
php 7.2

Comment: Hi Rakib, please [read this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and explain a little better what's your problem, what have you tried so far and a snippet of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test product was empty. create a test product first [switch viewing test data 
 on your stripe dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVtbd.png)